# Mpg123 play previous file

Tags: linux, console, mp3-player

Is it possible to use mpg123 to play previous file?

My normal usage on using mpg123

```
$ mpg123 somefolder/*.mp3
```

I know that to pause we can use `Ctlr+Z`, and `fg` to resume, `Ctrl+C` to play next song, but is it possible to play previous song?

Answer (score 3):

Ah nevermind, I found it, use:

```
mpg123 -C somefolder/*.mp3
```

copied from man file

Enable terminal control keys. By default use `s` or the  `space`  bar  to  stop/restart  (pause, unpause)  playback, `f` to jump forward to the next song, `b` to jump back to the beginning of the song, `,` to rewind, `.` to fast forward, and `q` to quit.  Type `h` for a  full  list  of  available controls.

copied from help console

```
[s] or [ ]      interrupt/restart playback (i.e. '(un)pause')
[f]     next track
[d]     previous track
[b]     back to beginning of track
[p]     loop around current position (don't combine with output buffer)
[.]     forward
[,]     rewind
[:]     fast forward
[;]     fast rewind
[>]     fine forward
[<]     fine rewind
[+]     volume up
[-]     volume down
[r]     RVA switch
[v]     verbose switch
[l]     list current playlist, indicating current track there
[t]     display tag info (again)
[m]     print MPEG header info (again)
[h]     this help
[q]     quit
[c] or [C]      pitch up (small step, big step)
[x] or [X]      pitch down (small step, big step)
[w]     reset pitch to zero
[k]     print out current position in playlist and track, for the benefit of some external tool to store bookmarks

Also, the number row (starting at 1, ending at 0) gives you jump points into the current track at 10% intervals.
```